# regex module | re.search() TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

Tags: python

Code:

```
import subprocess
from tqdm import tqdm
from time import sleep
import re


mac = input('Enter your MAC-Address: ')

def mac_eth0():
    for i in tqdm(range(3)):
        sleep(1)

    subprocess.call('ifconfig eth0 down', shell=True)
    subprocess.call(f'ifconfig eth0 hw ether {mac}', shell=True)
    subprocess.call('ifconfig eth0 up', shell=True)

    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(['ifconfig', 'eth0'])

    mac_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
    print(mac_result.group(0))

mac_eth0()
```

Error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/re.py", line 200, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=TypeError%3A+cannot+use+a+string+pattern+on+a+bytes-like+object -- please just search for the error message first. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Notice that you're not even asking a question!

Comment: `subprocess` gives you `bytes` and you have to `.decode()` it to `string`. OR you have to use `bytes` as regex - it means prefix `b` in `br"\w\w:...."`

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.check_output` returns raw bytes by default, and when using regexes in Python, you have to make sure your pattern and thing you’re matching on are the same type.

[Per subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), you can have `check_output` decode the bytes for you rather than returning bytes.

> By default, this function will return the data as encoded bytes. The actual encoding of the output data may depend on the command being invoked, so the decoding to text will often need to be handled at the application level.
>
> This behaviour may be overridden by setting text, encoding, errors, or universal_newlines to True as described in Frequently Used Arguments and `run()`.

A simple way to fix this is to specify your encoding as `utf-8` or `ascii` when calling `check_output`, like in this minimal example.

```
import re
import subprocess


def mac_eth0():
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(
        ['ifconfig', 'eth0'],
        encoding="utf-8"
    )
    mac_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
    print(mac_result.group(0))

mac_eth0()
```

Alternatively, you can specify `text=True`, which causes `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` to be processed as text (using either your environment locale or specified `encoding`):

```
import re
import subprocess


def mac_eth0():
    ifconfig_result = subprocess.check_output(
        ['ifconfig', 'eth0'],
        text=True
    )
    mac_result = re.search(r"\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w:\w\w", ifconfig_result)
    print(mac_result.group(0))

mac_eth0()
```

And running either of these examples on my machine gets me something like this

```
> python mactest.py
e0:ab:c4:16:e9:ff
```